# Using jar xvf to exctrat all archives in a directory? MacOS Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, zip, archive, iterm2

I am using jar xvf to try and extract about 400 .zip files from a folder. When I run the following:

```
jar xvf \*.zip
```

I am met with this error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: *.zip (No such file or directory)
at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:220)
at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:158)
at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:113)
at jdk.jartool/sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:400)
at jdk.jartool/sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1669)
```

However running the unzip command with *.zip after is working fine, albeit not unzipping the entire set of folders. 
How might I change the above command in the terminal so as to avoid extracting these archives one by one?

Comment: `find . -iname "*.zip" -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 -P {#TASKS} -J % jar xvf %`  (`-P` is for the number of tasks to spawn, one per core works well, but raise/lower depending upon hardware)